# Regular expression to find particular email addressses

Tags: java, regex

I have a list of following email addresses,

```
test1@khm.com,
test2@khm.com,
test3@yahoo.com
test4@gmail.com 
new1@gmail.com
```

How can I validate these email addresses using following email address

```
test.*@khm.com
```

Here I need to get the o/p as

```
test1@khm.com,
test2@khm.com
```

Comment: You mean this `"test\\d+@dhm\\.com"` ?

Comment: After test cab be anything....but the domain name should be perfect match

Comment: what does "perfect match" mean?

Comment: So how does your attempt not work?

Comment: Your regex works, just anchor it and escape the dot.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
^test[^@\\s]*@dhm\\.com$
```

`[^@]*` Matches any character but not of `@` zero or more times.

```
System.out.println("test1@dhm.com".matches("test[^@\\s]*@dhm\\.com"));
System.out.println("test2@dhm.com".matches("test[^@\\s]*@dhm\\.com"));
System.out.println("test4@gmail.com".matches("test[^@\\s]*@dhm\\.com"));
System.out.println("new1@gmail.com".matches("test[^@\\s]*@dhm\\.com"));
```

**Output:**

```
true
true
false
false
```

Comment: What about email addresses that contain multiple @ signs? :)

Comment: The @ is not the only character which would it make an invalid e-mail address-- all whitespace, for example.

Comment: @mest is there any problem with this answer?